# I have a column of text and text-formatted-numbers. If number;convert. If text;return text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table like so (the first column):

```
| Table  | What I want to achieve |
|--------|------------------------|
| 088888 | convert to number      |
| 88888  | convert to number      |
| 588888 | convert to number      |
| 688888 | convert to number      |
| V44100 | ignore and return text |
| W44101 | ignore and return text |
| S54001 | ignore and return text |
| V44102 | ignore and return text |
| BOLUTY | ignore and return text |
| SHOLIA | ignore and return text |
|--------|------------------------|
```

The table is generated from a database so all numbers comes formatted as text.

I want a formula that will help convert all text-formatted-numbers to numbers like the first 4 numbers in the cell above. the formula should be smart enough not to try to convert text to numbers, i.e when it encounters a text it should return the actual text.

I tried to use `=VALUE(A1)`, while it works for the first 4 numbers above, it returns #VALUE error when it encounters real texts (last 6 texts in column A of the table above.

I have another formula like this `(IF(OR(LEFT(A1)='1',LEFT(A1)='2',VALUE(A1),A1)` This works as desired but it will be too long as I want to test for prefix numbers `0 through 9` i.e `IF(OR) 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` etc

Is there a shorter/simpler way of achieving this without using the above unusually long formula?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a formula for this? Excel already has an inbuilt method for this...

Comment: @siddharth-rout and @pnuts Thanks. I have over a hundred tables with thousands of row, I'm looking for a way to build this into my formula so I wont have to do it manually with `convert to number` or `text to column`.

Comment: Are you aware that you can select `ALL` the cells starting from the first cell which has number stored as text and then do a mass conversion? you don't need to select all table separately? It is faster than formulas and less tedious?

Comment: Yes I know I can but I'd rather the template I'm building do this automatically if possible.

Comment: ok if you insist. Which excel version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I use Excel 2010

Comment: I hope there are no decimal values in Col A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments use the error checking to do a mass conversion but if you still insist on a formula then here it is.

```
=IFERROR(INT(A1),A1)
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you have decimal values in Col A then use `VALUE` instead of `INT`

Comment: Thanks @siddharth-rout, This works but I couldn't use it in a nested formula, I think I'll just use the built-in option you suggested earlier. Cheers.